# Breaking Down Type 1 .pfa Font File Format Using t1dsasm in C Programming

Tags: c, fonts, postscript

I've peered into several references that very exhaustively or minimally (it's hard to tell) convey instructions on how to program a .pfa font type (purportedly obsolete since 2005) t1utils has a [t1disasm.c](https://github.com/kohler/t1utils/blob/master/t1disasm.c) programming disassembly tool written in C that is made for decoding postscript and related packaged font program and charstring dictionaries. Would anyone like to break this down, specifically, in terms of the components that do not remain constant?

Comment: Doesn't sound particularly funny, why would anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You might find some components of the open source [Adobe Font Development Kit for OpenType (AFDKO)](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko) useful, specifically `tx` and `detype1`, the latter can decode a .pfa (or .pfb) into something a bit more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

A .pfa file is an Adobe Type 1 font file encoded as ascii (Printer Font ASCII) as opposed to binary *.pfb). You can find the Adobe type 1 font format specification [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/font/pdfs/T1_SPEC.pdf)

Part of the content of such a file is written in the PostScript programming language, though generally not the portion likely to be of interest to you.

Broadly speaking, none of the content remains constant though there are some predefined constant procedures. As djangodude said, if you explained what your goal is it would be easier to help.

Comment: Lets say I want to script a custom .pfa file type. The obvious distortion in all of this is in the redundantly encoded eexec section of its postscript.

Comment: Chances are I can interpret both "private dictionary" and "CharString dictionary" arrangement, but ultimately this portent of a .pfa's postscript must be encrypted for the font program to be complete and working.  It may suffice to have fuller insight into 1.) the human readable eexec with a common or working dictionary arrangements, and 2.) a basic and working C coding script that can demonstrate an accurate encryption according to the Adobe standard.

Comment: Here I've established a basic encryption method that implements a for() statement that prints obvious encrypted results:

int main()
{
  int r;

  char c[256] = "I am learning C programming language.";


for(r = 0; (r < 256 && c[r] != '\0'); r++)
        c[r] = c[r] + 3; 
        
        

      printf("\n%s\n", c);
    
   
   return 0;
} 

So, if I wanted to use this above C script example and inject adobe's restricted encryption standard into it. How can I get this to work?

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to do. Building a font isn't as simple as applying eexec encryption, that' sthe easy part. The eexec encryption isn't exacllty redundant, its a legacy of the original font format before it was published. In this case eexec does more than decrypt, it also executes the decrypted content. The Private and CharString dictionaries are PostScript language constructs, you can obviously interpret them without using a PostScript interpreter, but its not clear what you hope to gain from this.

Comment: If you're expecting me to write a decryption function for eexec then I'm afraid I'm not going to. There is one already available in t1disasm, use that.

Comment: No, I'm not expecting you to write the decryption function. Is there any way you can pull the open script relevant to the .pfa file type's binary encryption from t1asm? I want to build a font within the ASCII range.

Comment: The source code to the eexec encryption is in t1asm.c (not a script, its C language source code). The eexec encryption is performed by the eencrypt() function and the CharString encryption is performed by cencrypt(). Its a bit ugly since it uses global variables but its all there.

Comment: Adobe's C language source code for encryption is always limited to 3 global variables where 'c1' and 'c2' appear to be constant in corroboration with other examples. t1sasm.c appears to make 'r' more dubious with representations 'cr' and 'er' (eg. encrypt r). Is there any reason 'cr' would be valid for encryption in this specific circumstance? Is it safe to say that variable 'r' (or 'er') is the only one of these that needs to be specifically redefined? And how relevant is a 'charstring command' subroutine for all of this?  Will encryption still pan through without it?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by 'cr would be valid for encryption'. cr is for charstring encryption and er is for eexec encryption. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with global variables, but modern developers often avoid them because they don't work with threads. There are two kinds of encryption; CharString encryption and eexec encryption, detailed in Chapter 7 of the Type 1 font format specification. The encryption method is the same for each, but the seed (R) differs and the number of initial random bytes may differ as well. If you expect to decrypt a type 1 font you will need both

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. So, if I got this right: t1utls addresses both er and cr encrypt in a complex subroutine, and must perform encryption 2 times. I think another detraction on my part is that it's difficult for me to know whether any .pfa postscript examples that are posted openly are what they appear to be. Do you know of any unencrypted .pfa postscript examples that I can us t1sasm.c to test for proof positive?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I am still a little fuzzy on exactly what you want to do but I think the `detype1` program (source _and_ output) might be useful to you for understanding how to decode a PFA. Bonus is that the AFDKO code comes directly from the inventors of PostScript (Type1, PFA, etc.). `detype1`'s complement, `type1`, does the _encoding_ and that might also be useful to study. If we're still not getting you where you want, *please edit your question* and explain more thoroughly what you are trying to do.

Comment: The encryption and decryption algorithms for both CharString and eexec are the same, the only difference is in the value of the seed 'R'. t1asm/t1disasm therefore use the same code for both, but maintain different variables. Because the c1 and c2 variables maitain state, these (along with R) are mantained separtely. To apply encryption you start by encrypting the CharStrings. Then you encrypt all the Private information, including the CharStrings dictionary. You don't need unencrypted fonts to test t1asm, start with an encrypted font and use t1disasm to get an unencrypted font, then t1asm.

Comment: In terms of all unsigned variables. In answering to these a.) is it the fp name that is directly referential; in other words the name is for substitutes b.) does every font program name require a 'def' marker or is this merely academic c.) does the font program name in a Type1 postscript file have to directly correspond to its predesignated postscript file name?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'the fp name'. 'def' is not a marker, its a PostScript operator. Type 1 fonts are PostScript programs and are required to conform to the PostScript language. This is not a 'file format' its a program. When you call the definefont operator in PostScript it uses the name you supply as the font name. It does not use the name defined in the font. However, the dictionary built by the font program does contain the FontName key defined in the program, so it is accesible to the PostScript program.

Comment: Alright, so, in the afdko package.  There is an .pfa postscript example named "Type1.pfa." And I'm sorted of getting flushed out. Resetting 'global variables' was the key tech term, but there are other variables too. I get the sense, however, that not a lot has to change. What might help to put me on stable ground is in answer to the afdko's type1.c or t1util's  t1asm.c string which would need the especial program name (eg. ?type1.pfa def), and it would help to know in how many strings this convention would need to be addressed.

Comment: I'm sorry I simply don't understand what you are asking there. If you are talking about the PostScript 'def' operator, its defied in the PostScript Language Reference Manual. Its not a convention, its part of a program (again, Type 1 fonts are PostScript programs)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you guys actually tested to see whether either afdko or t1utils coding scripts in relation to Type1's work? I got both python and C compilers at my desk. afdko looks promising cause it appears to have all the relevant files in it. There's even a Type1_test.py script with Type1 IO samples. But running it don't show results. In t1utils in related Type1 utilities there appears to be consistent errors popping up in relation to variables unint16_t  and unint32_t not being declared, but are already associated with notable 5 digit numeric values.

Comment: t1utils, and in particular tidisasm and t1asm both work perfectly well for me on a variety of type 1 fonts. When you say 'variables unint16_t' I think you mean the **data type** uint16_t, which is a data type defined in the C source code, in t1asm.c and t1disasm.c.

Comment: Can you list all the files you used related to either t1disasm or t1asm in t1utils so I can corroborate them with what I have? And is there any way you can forward a sample of a working reconfigured t1asm.c or t1asm.c so I can compare this to an original?

Comment: That would be 'no'. All the files I have used are the ones supplied in t1tools. I have not 'reconfigured' t1asm.c or t1disasm.c (though I used them as the inspration to write CFF versions of both). The versions of t1asm and t1disasm I have are identical to the originals. This conversation is way too long and your questions no longer seem to be programming related so I'm not responding here any longer.

Comment: I catch your drift. The more and more I siphon through the t1utils it becomes apparent that not a lot should have to change. It looks like there are 2 consistent definite noticeable errors that pop up. One relates to my compiler not being able to read <include/lcdf/clp.h> header and definition types unsigned char 32 and 16 always turn up corrupted even though they've been present with consistently demonstrated binary numeric values. I also tried compiling t1sasm into an .exe in cmd and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

So, I sorted this one out with the least amount of hassle necessary. Anyone interested in Type1 fonts and their postscript innerworkings you should

1.) go to this site and download the relevant t1utils executables:  https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/cygwin/cygwin_v1.3.2/bin/

2.) drop them into the t1utils-master folder mentioned above along with your favorite font face types

3.) and run the respective compiled .exe