# Compiling t1sasm C program into an Executable

Tags: pdf, encoding, fonts, decoding, postscript

I'd like to get some insight into some old font postscripts, mainly the Type1 .pfas.  It looks like these are where font making really took off and their root programming is in C.  On github I noticed that while their are an upward thousands of coding scripts dedicated to like video games there, and in stark contrast there are no more than 20 give or take scripts dedicated to Type1s. The literature on programming Type1s is open and out there, but it looks like a lot of font makers have moved on to proprietary font and pdf making programs eg. fontforge and ghostscript, and I get the feeling that kind of thing has the potential to lead to blood loss.  Does anyone have any information on t1utils and its t1sasm and t1disasm c programs and how this programming is supposed to come together.  What's the best way to get these files to compile into .exe files?

Answer (score 0):

From the README at the [`t1utils` repo](https://github.com/kohler/t1utils):

> You need an ANSI C compiler, such as gcc.
>
> Just type ./configure, then make. make install will build and install the utilities and their manual pages.
>
> ./configure accepts the usual options. See INSTALL for more details. The most commonly used option is --prefix, which can be used to install the utilities in a place other than /usr/local.

If you are on a Mac or Linux machine, you should be pretty well set to perform the above with no trouble, just clone, `./configure`, and `make`. It will be more challenging for Windows (not even sure the project supports it).

But as I did with your [other question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814173/breaking-down-type-1-pfa-font-file-format-using-t1dsasm-in-c-programming), I'd strongly recommend that you look at the open source [Adobe Font Development Kit for OpenType - AFDKO](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko) which is under active development, and is written and maintained primarily (but by no means exclusively) by Adobe employees (inventors of the Type1 format and PDF). Installing the AFDKO will give you pre-built executables for Mac, Linux, and Windows, ready to go. There are numerous utilities for decompiling and compiling Type1 and other font formats. You can examine the C (and Python) source code for these tools to see exactly how things are done, if you wish to have a deeper understanding of the Type1 format.